# Create sf lines from data.frame with four columns of long lat coordinates

Tags: r, sf, linestring

I want to create an `sf` object from a `data.frame` that contains multiple coordinates under different columns for each row. In the data below, each ID contains start and end coordinates for both latitude and longitude.

[image]

```r
structure(list(ID = c("1001A", "1002A", "1003A", "1004A", "1005A", 
"1006A", "1007A", "1008A", "1009A", "1010A"), StartLat = c(33.53418, 
33.60399, 33.40693, 33.64672, 33.57127, 33.42848, 33.54936, 33.49554, 
33.5056, 33.61696), StartLong = c(-112.09114, -111.92731, -112.02982, 
-111.92548, -112.04899, -112.0998, -112.09123, -111.9687, -112.05629, 
-111.98657), EndLat = c(33.53488, 33.60401, 33.40687, 33.64776, 
33.57125, 33.42853, 33.54893, 33.49647, 33.5056, 33.61654), EndLong = c(-112.09114, 
-111.93097, -112.03429, -111.93031, -112.04807, -112.09929, -112.09122, 
-111.97105, -112.0541, -111.98657)), row.names = c(3028L, 8618L, 
6322L, 1171L, 691L, 6590L, 2008L, 4552L, 2894L, 1909L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using the sf package's `st_as_sf` function, but it yields an error:

```r
dfr_sf <- st_as_sf(dfr, coords = c(c("StartLong", "EndLong"), c("StartLat", "EndLat")), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
#> Error in points_rcpp(as.matrix(cc), dim) : 
#>  dim(pts)[2] == nchar(gdim) is not TRUE
```

The start and end coordinates in each row define a road segment. All the coordinates should go under the geometry column in the final `sf` object so that these can be plotted as polylines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm solving your problem by looping through lines in the `data.frame` and by building the `LINESTRING` matrix of each pair of coordinates

```r
library(sf)
ls <- apply(dfr, 1, function(x) 
{
  v <- as.numeric(x[c(3,5,2,4)])
  m <- matrix(v, nrow = 2)
  return(st_sfc(st_linestring(m), crs = 4326))
})
ls = Reduce(c, ls)
ls$ID = dfr$ID
```

Comment: You need to flip the lat-long coordinates. Check the `st_bbox(ls)`...

Comment: This example produces a linestring for the given coordinates. As per my original post, I'm looking to create an sf object that would hold the IDs in one column and their corresponding coordinates as 'geometry' in another column.

Comment: `ls$ID = dfr$ID`